# Difference in meaning and usage between “macrologia”, “periergia” and “bomphiologia”

Tags: meaning, terminology, word-usage, rhetoric

All of these terms are devices that can describe something that is superfluous but how do these terms differ?

The *Silva Rhetoricae* (Gideon Burton, [rhetoric.byu.edu](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/)) lists them under "[figures of excess and superfluity](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/Groupings/of%20Excess%20and%20Superfluity.htm)" and provides the following short definitions:

- [macrologia](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/M/macrologia.htm):

  > ma-cro-lo'-gi-a   from Gk. *macro*, "long" and *logos*, "speaking"
  >   
  > ***macrology***
  >
  > Longwindedness. Using more words than are necessary in an attempt to appear eloquent.
- [periergia](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/P/periergia.htm):

  > pe-ri-er'-gi-a   from Gk. *peri*, "exceedingly" and *ergon*, "work"
  >   
  > ***sedulitas superflua
  >   
  > over labour, curious***
  >
  > Overuse of words or figures of speech. As such, it may simply be considered synonymous with macrologia. However, as Puttenham's term suggests, periergia may differ from simple superfluity in that the language appears over-labored.
- [bomphiologia](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/B/bomphiologia.htm):

  > bom-phi-o-lo'-gi-a   
  > ***verborum bombus***
  >
  > Exaggeration done in a self-aggrandizing manner, as a braggart.

Is all of this correct? Can anyone give a more detailed description of how these three terms differ?

Comment: *Periergia* actually exists: "The use of an excessively elaborate or elevated style to discuss a trivial matter." You need to take more care with your leg-pulls.

Comment: Neither of the other  two are in either Webster or the OED.  Asking about such "superfluous" words  (particularly without any attempt at a reference) looks like a joke that fell flat.

Comment: I'm a tad taken back but I am not "leg-pull[ing]". You can still find all three terms in the [Silva Rhetoricae](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/Groupings/of%20Excess%20and%20Superfluity.htm), the terms have been used in [literature analyses](https://books.google.com/books?id=OKxwOqUgNvkC&pg=PA156&lpg=PA156&dq=bomphiologia&source=bl&ots=Fh204B-FnF&sig=pXKNSpTWgfhuNOz0A7R9chBb7eA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7oqKX3I3bAhVRwlkKHThvD-Y4ChDoAQhbMA0#v=onepage&q=bomphiologia&f=false), etc. Both of the terms in question can also be found on [Google's Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has four close votes, so I need to close it so I can immediately reöpen it now that it has research. :)

Comment: @sumelic ftfy :)

Comment: My apologies, I was not aware that I needed to reference the terms. Thank you for the edits to the post, as well @sumelic !

Comment: I was curious about the formation/etymology of "bomphiologia", so I asked a question about it on the [Latin Stack Exchange site](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6520/is-there-any-explanation-for-the-formation-of-bomphiologia-as-a-greek-word-for) (I just wanted to let you know)